# Table size (Mo) with hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, size

In fact I'm developing the dashboard page of my web application using spring mvc and hibernate as a persistence framework. I have to get the table size (Mo) in order to render it to the administrator. 
I have been searching for such a topic but in vain, I just want to know if hibernate can provides the table size as it can do the following SQL command:

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT(ROUND(sum(DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024), 2), 'Mo')

FROM information_schema.TABLES 

WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nom_base_de_donnees'

AND table_name='nom_table'
```

I've been busy in other things, now I tried and it works good. I'm posting the dao method in case someone need it.

```
 @Override
public List getTableSize() {
    Session session =sessionFactory.openSession();
    String sql="SELECT round(sum(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024,2) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'email_center_v2'AND table_name = 'message'";
    Query query=session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    List result=query.list();
    session.colse();
    return result;
}
```

just call the method in the Controller and add the result to the appropriate view

Comment: Just execute that sql... Hibernate has nothing to do with it...

Comment: OK thanks, i'm gonna try it

Comment: One flaw in your code you should either use `getCurrentSession` or at leat close the session when u sing `openSession` as you are now leaking sessions and thus connections. I suggest `getCurrentSession` as that will let spring manage the session.

Comment: yes good point i used to close the hibernate session every time i use it  ,my bad i just forget it in this method 
thanks